# Fortify scan Null Dereference issue at For Each loop VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dereference, fortify, null-pointer

Our application is written in VB.Net.
On scanning our application in HP Fortify, Null Dereference issue was pointed at the only the For Each ... Next loop in the few pages.
What could be the reason the Null Reference is shown only at the For each loop. At all places where the For Each loop is used in the application the null dereference is pointing to the "Next" of the For Each loop.
Please help resolve this scan issue.
A sample code snippet from our application is below.

```
If Request.QueryString("mode") IsNot Nothing Then
                        mode = Request.QueryString("mode")
                    End If
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    For Each col In gridTemp.Columns
                        Select Case col.HeaderText
                            Case "ID"
                                col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", True, False)
                            Case "Name"
                                col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", True, False)
                            Case "Balance"
                                col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", False, True)
                            Case "Dues"
                                col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", True, False)
                            Case "Contact"
                                col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", False, True)
                        End Select
                    Next
```

Comment: Can you please show at which line your `Null Dereference error` is showing up?

Comment: Whet is the value of `mode` before the `If` statement at the start of your snippet of code?

Comment: What variable is producing the finding?  `Request`, `gridTemp`, `dfc` and `col` could all theoretically be null and you aren't checking any of them in this code snippit.

Comment: The null dereference is shown at the line containing next.

Comment: mode is set to String.empty before the If.
We tried adding Not Nothing checks before the For Each loop didnt work still..

Comment: In the entire application the Null Dereference issue is shown at 4 places totally. All 4 are pointing to the Next statement of the For Each loop. Moreover For Each is used only in those 4 places in the application. Could it be something with the For Each loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way we've found to get around this is to convert for each loops into for loops.  In this case, try using something like

```
For I as Integer = 0 to gridTemp.Columns.Count - 1  
 Dim col as Column(i)  
 Select Case col.HeaderText  

 Case "ID"  
      col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", True, False)  
 Case "Name"  
      col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", True, False)  
 Case "Balance"  
      col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", False, True)  
 Case "Dues"  
      col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", True, False)  
 Case "Contact"  
      col.Visible = IIf(mode = "Admin", False, True)  
 End Select  
Next
```

Comment: If a tool is persuading you to write less-safe code (e.g turning foreach into for) then perhaps you should use a different tool.

Comment: Would love to use a different tool, but unfortunately it's required for the client and many other clients in my industry.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, but unfortunately this is the tool I'm stuck with.  The other option is to mark it as "not an issue" and explain why it's not an issue.